# The line $y = \sqrt2x$ + $\sqrt3$

Tags: field-theory

Does the line $y = \sqrt2x + \sqrt3$ contain a point $(x,y)$ such that $x$ is rational and $y$ is rational?

I looked at the line $y = \sqrt2x$ and proved it has just one such point $(0,0)$.  I also proved that $y = \sqrt2x + \sqrt2$ has just one such point.  In both of these proofs I assumed $x$ and $y$ were both rational and I got to a contradiction right away.

Is there an easy way to show a similar result for the given line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we can use the same easy style of proof to show that the line doesn't contain such a point. Suppose instead that such a point $(x, y) \in \mathbb Q^2$ exists. Note that $x \neq 0$, since otherwise we have $y = \sqrt 3 \notin \mathbb Q$. Then observe that:
$$
y^2 = 2x^2 + 2\sqrt 6 x + 3 \iff \sqrt 6 = \frac{y^2 - 2x^2 - 3}{2x} \in \mathbb Q
$$
a contradiction. So no such $(x, y) \in \mathbb Q^2$ exists, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Answer (score 2):

If
$y = \sqrt{n}x + \sqrt{m}$
where
$m$ is a non-square integer
and $x$ and $y$ are rational,
by multiplying,
we can make $x$ and $y$ integers.

Then
$y - \sqrt{m}= \sqrt{n}x $.
Squaring,
$y^2-2y\sqrt{m}+m
= nx^2$,
or
$\sqrt{m}
= \frac{nx^2-y^2-n}{2y}$,
so that
$\sqrt{m}$
is rational.

But $\sqrt{m}$
is not rational.

This is a contradiction.

Comment: @ marty cohen  Yes.  Thank you for this generalization.